# How add property to EF4

Tags: entity-framework-4

How add new property to WorkSpace which will show the name room?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This property cannot be defined in entity designer unless it is also defined in the database as column of `WorkPanel` table. Create partial class to generated entity and add custom property:

```
public partial class WorkPanel
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return (Table != null && Table.Room != null) ? Table.Room.Name : null;
        }
    }
}
```

To use this property you must always load `Table` and `Room` entity with `WorkPanel` (either by eager or lazy loading).

Comment: Not see this property. Where exactly should do it ? I have WorkSpaceService.cs and WorkSpaceService.metadata.cs ?

Comment: What is WorkSpace? Why you use terms you didn't described in the question?

Comment: Sorry. WorkSpace == WorkPAnel

Comment: How did you generate your entity classes?

Comment: from database. after create DomainService